# Generate 2D grid with alternation probability

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology

I want to generate a 2D grid environment with rewards distributed (1s are rewards, 0s are no rewards) based on an alternation probability as defined in this paper by Falk and Konald (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.412.7679&rep=rep1&type=pdf). The basic idea is that once a random square is seeded (top left, say) as 1 or 0, then the probability of the adjacent square staying the same as the previous, or switching - is given by the probability of alternation. The paper describes the generation process as going from 'left to right' and 'top to bottom'. I am not clear on how the authors intended to implement it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is on the implementation of statistical processes and should go to CrossValidated, or even StackOverflow for a more programming based approach